# Ofbiz Websocket Example setup not connecting wss

Tags: ofbiz

I am trying to setup websocket environment by setting up ofbiz 16.11.04 build and from `catalina.properties`, i set `websocket=true`.

I tried to get into "Example", i am getting following error

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at
>   wss://localhost:8443/example/ws/pushNotifications

is there any setup I am missing or anyone facing this issue

Answer (score 2):

I fixed that recently, please check https://s.apache.org/k4Vo and http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=r1819814

For convenience, here is the patch

```
--- framework/catalina/ofbiz-component.xml  2018/01/02 12:25:33 1819813
+++ framework/catalina/ofbiz-component.xml  2018/01/02 12:26:29 1819814
@@ -22,6 +22,7 @@
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ofbiz.apache.org/dtds/ofbiz-component.xsd">
     <resource-loader name="main" type="component"/>
+    <classpath type="dir" location="config"/>
     <entity-resource type="model" reader-name="main" loader="main" location="entitydef/entitymodel.xml"/>

     <container name="catalina-container" loaders="main" class="org.apache.ofbiz.catalina.container.CatalinaContainer">
```

Comment: Hi after adding config file in classpath, websocket started working, thank you

Comment: Thanks Nick for the direction, I have added the patch